# Why oBIX and CoAP together required

Tags: iot, coap

I am working on an building automation IOT system which has both oBIX and CoAP application to provide web services. As per my knowledge CoAP layer operates above oBIX handler. Also some interfaces of oBIX is similar to CoAP.

My query is why oBIX is required? Why oBIX is necessary if CoAP is already avaliable?

Answer (score 0):

In IOT, CoAP is used as Binding protocol for oBIX interfaces. The oBIX specification provides for bindings using REST (using HTTP or CoAP), SOAP, and WebSocket to talk with web/internet.In many cases, your choice of binding may be dictated by the application needs, such as if you are implementing a server in a constrained environment, or for an enterprise level application.

For CoAP binding following CoAP intefaces are mapped with oBIX requests:

**OBIX Request - - HTTP Interfaces**
Read - - - - - - - - - GET
Write - - - - - - - - - PUT
Invoke - - - - - - - - POST
Delete - - - - - - - - DELETE